# EXCEL: use SUMPRODUCT or COUNTIF?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

A quick questioon about a formula. I search a method that will do this : it will check a column and if it meets a value, it should determine if this value is at least in one of two ranges (16-20 or 80-84) and it displays the number of values in these ranges once the column check is over.

For instance : if `G1:G5` has (1,16,25,56,82), the formulas should send "`2`".

I'm currently using this formula but I don't know if it's optimal, if you have better alternative and/or if `countif()` could work / will be better :

```
=SUM(SUMPRODUCT((G$1:G$1000>15)*(G$1:G$1000<21)),SUMPRODUCT((G$1:G$1000>79)*(G$1:G$1000<85)))
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

You also can use:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(G1:G5;">=16";G1:G5;"<=20");COUNTIFS(G1:G5;">=80";G1:G5;"<=84"))
```